# Можно ли отследить количество скачиваний файла

Tags: javascript, html, css

Файл для скачивания находиться в корне проекта. Можно ли отследить количество скачиваний/кликов файла. Страница через git page. Не особо шарю в серверной части и как это всё устроено. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете подключить гугл аналитику и повесить на ссылку на скачивание счетчик.
https://siteclinic.ru/blog/seo-instrumenty/otslezhivanie-klikov-po-knopkam-sayta/

Либо воспользоваться подобным функционалом у яндекса
https://yandex.ru/support/metrica/simple-goal/click.html

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно без сторонних сервисов - создать счётчик, который будет увеличиваться с каждым нажатием на ссылку скачать и результат записываться в БД или в файле на сервере.